# How can I change the default settings in Visual VM?

Tags: java, groovy, visualvm

When trying to profile groovy code in Visual VM, I have to manually add the setting to filter out `groovy.*` and `org.codehaus.*` classes from profiling every time.  Is there a place I can make this the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to Tools > Options > Profiling and create the presets you want.

Comment: Yes, this worked, I had to download a newer version of VisualVM for presets to be there (1.3.1)